# The MySQL service is in the status "starting" on windows

Tags: windows-server-2003, mysql, service

I have several months working to "MySQL-5-1-47" on windows 2003. When I restarted, the service "MySQL" stay in this state "starting".

The only way to raise the service was running the program directly:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld
```

This is the MySQL error log

```
100906 16:07:29 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
100906 16:07:32  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
100906 16:07:37 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
100906 16:07:38  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
100906 16:07:38 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

100906 16:07:39  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
100906 16:17:21 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
100906 16:17:22  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
100906 16:22:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
100906 16:22:02  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
100906 16:22:02 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
100906 16:22:02 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.47-community'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

The last lines are after loading the program from the shell

Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49637.  It describes the same symptoms that you are having.  Ensure that your variables (such as tempdir) are defined correctly.

Answer (score 5):

I saved by accident my configuration "my.ini" using "UTF8 with BOM". After changed the charset to "UTF-8" (or ASCII) it's working again.

Try an editor other than notepad, in visual studio code I was able to check the encoding correctly.

Comment: It works for me with MySQL 5.7 and windows server 2012 when 2019.

Comment: Thanks. Editing the file with notepad was exactly my problem. I used notepad++ to save as UTF-8 again.

Comment: Damn, notepad tricked me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Hahaha, thanks a lot it work for me.. Just, wanna give more detail guide who will see this forum, you need open the file my.ini from C:/ProgramData/MySQL, after that you need open the file using "Notepad++" (Notepad Windows is source of problem), change the encode to be "UTF-8" and save again. then you need stop the Mysql service from task manager, after that try again to start the service mysql. Gudluck